# Error: "The JWT string must have two dots"

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, sha256

I try to parse Bearer Tokens from a Http Request to get the client information in the next step. It works most of the time really well but sometimes sentry throws me an error: "The JWT string must have two dots".
How can I prevent this case?

```
$bearerToken = Request::bearerToken();
$parsedToken = (new Parser())->parse($bearerToken);
```

Comment: Is someone maliciously editing the JWT token? Also, try adding a try/catch block around the parser, to report back to sentry the actual bearer token if there's an error, so you can see what is happening.

Comment: @FrankerZ I don't edit the token maybe a user does. I try it with a try/catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint from @FrankerZ with try / catch block works pretty well!

```
try {
   $bearerToken = Request::bearerToken();
   $parsedToken = (new Parser)->parse($bearerToken);
   $tokenId = $parsedToken->getHeader('jti');
   $this->client = Token::find($tokenId)->client;
} catch (Exception $e) {
   $this->client = [];
}
```

Comment: This just catches the error. Can we say something about, why it happens?